# A quotation from Laplace or Lagrange?

Tags: histoire

I read a quotation from a famous French mathematician a few years ago (in English translation), and I am trying to find it again.

I believe it was attributed to either Pierre-Simon Laplace or Joseph-Louis Lagrange. I don't remember the exact phrase, but the gist of it was something like, "the key to a long and happy life is to be on good terms with the government of wherever you live".

If anyone knows what I'm talking about, I'd really appreciate a source!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the French language itself. There are subreddits for this type of thing. Off-topic imo.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the original, but most likely it'd be from Laplace, not just a mathematician but a politician known principally for his ability to change his allegiance in a blink to any incoming ruler..